# node.couchapp.js & cradle - complementary or tools for same thing?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I want to start testing CouchDB and Node.js but having problems to figure out what tools to use.

Can I do everything I want with [cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) and node.js? Or do I need [node.couchapp.js](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js/tree/)? Also is this [follow](https://github.com/iriscouch/follow) application re-implementation of something cradle does too?

Some birth pains still visible as CouchDB and Node.js are both pretty new, and tools and utilities are still evolving. Relying on some random github projects is not amusing, so trying to keep these dependencies low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB has a [simple HTTP API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/api.html), then you can use any HTTP client library to talk with CouchDB. [Cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) is sometimes handy, sometimes not, depending on the use-case. The important thing to keep in mind is that, whatever library you choose as CouchDB client library, you can always fall back to using "pure HTTP", and it's often very easy to do: it's only JSON and HTTP.

For writing [couchapps](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/standalone.html), the reasoning is the same: you can start as simple as writing a JSON with the design document and PUTting it in a db; you can use a minimalistic tool as [node.couchapp.js](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js); or you can use something more sophisticated as [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica). However, under the hood, you are always doing simple HTTP calls to send and receive some JSON.

Answer (score 2):

cradle is for talking to a couchdb, inserting and getting documents and so on. couchapp is for something else, you can use it to put some logic (views) or even entire webinferfaces with images and so on into the database. You'll probably need both.